# menuitemclick event firing on Master but not child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a menu on a master page with the following:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="SiteMapDataSource" ShowStartingNode="false" /> 

<asp:Menu ID="mnuMain1" runat="server" RenderingMode="List" StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass="selected" IncludeStyleBlock="false" DataSourceID="siteMapDataSource" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" OnMenuItemClick="mnuMain1_MenuItemClick">
         <DataBindings>
            <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="SiteMapNode" TextField="Title" />
         </DataBindings>
</asp:Menu>
```

Code in .Master.cs file:

```
protected void mnuMain1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem mnu = e.Item;
    }
```

I have created a webpage that inherits from the master - this asks the user to populate a Location field. When the user clicks on a menu item it needs to check the Location field has a value before proceeding. I have a MenuItemClick eventhandler declared in the code. The MenuItemClick event fires on the Master but not on the inherited page.

Have I missed something really obvious?

Comment: You `inherit` the master page or you reference it with `MasterPageFile` in the `Page` declaration of your web form?

Comment: It is referenced in the Page declaration: `MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"`

Comment: I guess I'm struggling to understand why you want to call this menu (which is in your masterpage) with code in page.

Comment: Have added some more details - basically I have more logic in the page that inherits from the Master. When the menu item is clicked it needs to perform a check before navigating away from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoEventWireup doesn't work on the page that uses the master page. You have to explicitly bind the event receiver. You can do this by exposing the control as a properly on the master page and then binding to the event in the child page.

Check out this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36055/Interaction-Between-Content-Page-and-Master-Page